# how do i make the option selected in append jquery in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects

How can I make the `option` selected according to the value I get from `value[0]` in the loop?

```js
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $("#cektubuh").append(               
    `<tr>
      <td> 
        <select name="duration_type[]" class="form-control" required>
          // here I want to add the selected option according to $ {value [0]}
          <option value="Semester">Semester</option>
          <option value="Month">Month</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>`
  });
});
```

Comment: Are all the `select` elements you create to be set with the value of `value[0]`? If so just do `$('#cektubuh select').val(value[0])` **outside** of the `each()` loop

Comment: @manikantgautam that makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no sir, There are other select options that need to be selected, val [0] is just an example

Comment: Ok, so how does `value[0]` change within the loop? I presume the index changes?

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided an example of the `data`, there is no way to know what values are being used here or how they compare. Here is a basic example based on what you have provided.

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
  var row = $("<tr>").appendTo($("#cektubuh"));
  var cell = $("<td>").appendTo(row);
  var sel = $("<select>", {
    name: "duration_type[]",
    class: "form-control"
  }).prop("required", true).appendTo(cell);
  $("<option>", {
    value: v[0]
  }).html(v[0]).prop("selected", true).appendTo(sel);
  $("<option>", {
    value: "Semester"
  }).html("Semester").appendTo(sel);
  $("<option>", {
    value: "Month"
  }).html("Month").appendTo(sel);
});
```

If it's more complex or has multiple elements, please provide an example of the structure so that a more complete answer can be shown.

Answer (score 0):

if you have `value` which belongs to options list and you want to show as `selected option`
just do this.

```
var value = 'some value';
$('name="duration_type[]"').val(value);
```

it will show that value as selected.